# How to access this inside a JS class if?

Tags: javascript, class, this

**Goal**
Reach the "smartest" way of accessing `this` inside a `if` in a method of a JS class.

**Description**
In my case i'm talking about the the first two lines of the `run` method and the last line of `run`.
`element.addEventlistener(this.listener, this.method)` doesn't work.
So i do for example `const listener = this.listener` in the `run` method.
Is there a way to avoid this?

Here is the whole class:

```
import GetElements from "./GetElementsByClassName";

export default class RegisterFunction {
    constructor(className, listener, method) {
        this.className = className;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.method = method;
    }

    run() {
        const listener = this.listener;
        const method = this.method;
        const elements = (new GetElements(this.className)).findElements();
        if (Array.isArray(elements) && elements.length > 0) {
            elements.forEach(function (element) {
                element.addEventListener(listener, method)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an arrow function --> `elements.forEach((element) => {...})`

Comment: You could also pass the value of `this` as an optional fourth argument to `.forEach()`